# Ionic 2: Ionic serve works fine, but gets stuck on loading screen when deployed to iOS

Tags: xcode, ionic2

This is the first time I'm running into this issue in Ionic 2, but basically, I took the build of https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app as of today's date and moved my files from another project into this one, mostly so I could take advantage of the latest Ionic 2 functionality. When I run `ionic serve`, everything loads up fine in the browser.

However, when I run `ionic build ios` then build it onto my iOS device, I get no errors, but the screen just gets stuck on the ionic splash screen. What's interesting is that my files from the other project would deploy onto my device no problem, as well as when I deployed the ionic conference app. I'm not exactly sure what I could have done to cause this problem, but I did change add a line in my config.xl`<allow-navigation href="*"/>`

Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: Can you provide the errors shown using debugging in Safari when running on your device?

Comment: I just ran into this problem. Not sure where the issue might be. Any luck?